# Stuck on an ASP.NET/WCF WSDL Parsing Error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF Web Service that my ASP.NET app uses.  It has been working fine for quite some time.

I just added in a Dev Express Grid (and the Dev Express DLLs) and a new page that uses them and now I am getting parsing errors on the WSDL.

But the weird part is that it works **fine on my machine** but **fails on the web server machine**.  (Both are connecting to the same web services WSDL.)

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Server Error in '/MyWebAppWebDev' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'MyWebAppService'.
Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'WebClientApp.MyWebAppService.ReferenceUpdatesDataContract, WebClientApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' with data contract name 'ReferenceUpdatesDataContract' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebAppServiceLibrary.DataContracts' cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to exclude this type from referenced types.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMyWebAppReferenceDataServiceLib']
Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMyWebAppReferenceDataServiceLib']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='MyWebAppServicesDefaultEndpoint']
Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='MyWebAppServicesDefaultEndpoint']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='MyWebAppReferenceDataServiceLib']/wsdl:port[@name='MyWebAppServicesDefaultEndpoint']

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: /MyWebAppWebDev/App_WebReferences/MyWebAppService/    Line: 1
```

I am completely stumped on this.  I have checked my web.config endpoint address and it is spot on (and notably is not in the error message above).

Any ideas would be welcomed.

---

Things I have tried:

- Giving permissions to C:\Windows\temp to my Website user name
- Giving permissions to C:\Windows\temp to my App pool user name
- Checking to see that none of my data contracts are generic and have IsReference=true in them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Skype? Seems like something is already using up a port for that web site, try browsing the site in a web browser to confirm.

Comment: The web server hosting this site is a Virtual Machine that is dedicated to hosting this web site.  (no skype).  The error message above is what I get when I try to browse to the site.  (thanks for the idea though)